# Automatic Formula when Inserting a New Row in between in Google Sheet without Circular Dependency

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I was trying to automatically add formulas when a new row is inserted in between and I did suceed with using arrayformula but now it gives error of circular dependecy. I do NOT want to use a SCRIPT for this. I tried too many methods like SUMIF, INDIRECT, etc. but it ain't working for me. I have made a DEMO sheet if someone can solve.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J1Lmz0QrGRUyknTc1GlxwS7p6uJdSojlhEB-HkpcW6M/edit?usp=sharing

I have written the original formula as well as the arrayformula that gives error.
Wil be greatly helpful if someone can solve.

Thank you :)

EDIT:
This was solved by rockinfreakshow but I have posted a new question for other cells:
[Google Sheets LAMBDA Blank cells with IF condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109146/google-sheets-lambda-blank-cells-with-if-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this for `Total Qty`

```
={"total qty";map(indirect("B3:B"),indirect("E3:E"),lambda(Σ,Δ,if(Σ="",,sumif(B3:Σ,Σ,E3:Δ))))}
```

- Replace `Column_E` within the formula to `Column_F` for `Total Invested`

[image]

Comment: This works but I have more colums which ain't working by simply change the columns to f, g, and so on. I have add a new sheet in the workbook with all columns. Please check if they are possible.

Comment: Any Ideas.. I am trying on a copy workbook.. some I am able to get it working but some like avg price, last purchase price, etc.. I am unable to calculate :(

Comment: I have posted a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109146/google-sheets-lambda-blank-cells-with-if-condition