# Google Sheets LAMBDA Blank cells with IF condition

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, array-formulas, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I was trying to automatically add formulas when a new row is inserted in between and I did suceed with using arrayformula but now it gives error of circular dependecy. I do NOT want to use a SCRIPT for this. I tried too many methods like SUMIF, INDIRECT, etc. but it ain't working for me. I have made a DEMO sheet if someone can solve.

Total qty and Total invested was solved by user rockinfreakshow using MAP and LAMBDA.

After that I tried in other columns and after some trial and error I was able to get it working but I am still unable to replicate "WITHOUT LAMBDA" sheet. I am unable to get the blanks. Please a look at the sheet and see if any of you can solve or make the formulas more better.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cr75E1u9SwnS9C3MpSnS0993MgNsZnnF4Xqm7cAjkyU/edit?usp=sharing

I have written the original formula in "WITHOUT LAMBDA" which gives blank cells properly and trail  & error has been done in "WITH LAMBDA" sheet. Wil be greatly helpful if someone can solve.

Thank you :)

Original Question here:
[Automatic Formula when Inserting a New Row in between in Google Sheet without Circular Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100065/automatic-formula-when-inserting-a-new-row-in-between-in-google-sheet-without-ci/76100251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these for `Avg Price` and `Target Price` columns. Hopefully you can adapt the remaining 7 column(formulas) based on these 2 since they seem to follow the same design structure and all...

***Avg Price***

```
={"Avg Price";map(indirect("B3:B"),indirect("G3:G"),indirect("H3:H"),lambda(etfcode,totalqty,totalinvested,
                  if(etfcode="",,if(etfcode<>offset(etfcode,1,),iferror(totalinvested/totalqty),))))}
```

***Target Price***

```
={"Target Price";map(indirect("I3:I"),lambda(avgprice,if(avgprice="",,avgprice*(1+3%))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you so much. I will check this more when I come on the PC and mark it as solved if it's done properly by me.

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you so much. Btw where do you learn all this. I also want to learn.

Comment: Sorry I do not have anything specific to point at(to learn). its just the practice of creating formulas for wide variety of scenarios is what usually works for me in general:)